# Why a[21] is not equal to a[021]?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int a[500];
int main()
{
    a[21]=10;
    if(a[21]==a[021])puts("Yes");
    else puts("No");
    return 0;
}
```

`g++ -std=c++11`

The output is `No`, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: `021` is an octal literal -- 17 in decimal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ a leading 0 on an integer literal means that value is in octal (similar to the way that 0x21 means that value is in hexadecimal).

Each of these values will be different. Here's a quick online demo:

http://cpp.sh/3cws4n

Note: the default output format for `cout` is decimal so the values you see are in decimal.